# React Vite error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

The page is working on running `yarn dev`, but if I'm going to `build` and `preview` it using yarn the page is empty and the error occurred "**Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')**".

[image]

It is working on codesandbox, I don't now if i missed something else. But I think because of an empty `array` initilization?

Here is the code.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from 'styled-components';

const DivArea = styled.div`
    &.brdr-right {
        border-right: 1px solid white;
    }
`;

const AddSection = styled.div`
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    position: relative;
`;

const CloseBtn = styled.div`
    position:absolute;
    right:-.5rem;
    top:-.5rem;
    background-color:orange;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding:.1rem .7rem;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
`;


const MainWireframe = () => {
    const storedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getVal'));

    const [val,setVal] = useState(storedItems);
    const handleAdd = () =>{
        const addValue = `${val.length + 1}`;
        setVal([...val, addValue]);
    }
    const handleDelete = (index) =>{
        const deleteValue = val.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
        setVal(deleteValue);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('getVal', JSON.stringify(val));
      }, [val]);

  return (
    <>
        <DivArea className="three brdr-right">
                <div className="v--text-center">
                    {val.map((element, index)=>{
                        return(
                        <AddSection key={index} className="v-row-section" draggable="true">
                                <div>Element {element} / Index {index}</div>
                                <CloseBtn onClick={()=>handleDelete(index)}>x</CloseBtn>
                        </AddSection>
                        )
                    })}
                    <button onClick={()=>handleAdd()}>Add Section</button>
                </div>
        </DivArea>
    </>
  )
}

export default MainWireframe
```

Comment: Try `const [val, setVal] = useState(storedItems || []);`